# Rxjava : i don't know why this program don't print

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

i don't know why this program don't print. I want print String Object whenever 1 seconds. So I use interval. this program normally compile. but result don't print. why? Help. (I'm Korean. So English is immature. sorry)

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){



        String str1 = "Apple";

        String str2 = "Banana";

        String str3 = "Boy";



        ObservableSource tim = Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        ObservableSource ss = Observable.just(str1,str2,str3);





        Observable.zip(tim,ss,new BiFunction() {



            @Override

            public String apply(Long t1, String t2) throws Exception {

                System.out.println("ddd");

                return t1+t2;

            }







        })

        .subscribe(new DefaultObserver() {



            @Override

            public void onNext(String t) {

                System.out.println(t);

            }



            @Override

            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                System.out.println("Error!!!");}



            @Override

            public void onComplete() {

                System.out.println("Complete!!!");

            }

        });





    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your observable **interval** it make your pipeline pass from **sync** to **async**, so it´s running in another thread and that´s why you cannot see any print onNext or onComplete.

Just to prove you my theory add

```
Thread.sleep(5000)
```

After your subscription.

If you´re learning RxJava you can consider take a look to this examples https://github.com/politrons/reactive